# Is the Thompson Group F a subgroup of the Baumslag-Solitar group BS(2,1)?

Tags: group-theory

The title pretty much sums it up : I'm wondering if BS(2,1) contains the Thompson Group F ?

Comment: BS(2,1) is metabelian, yet F is not.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is **no**. This probably isn't the easiest argument, but it's the first one that came to my mind:

1. Subgroups of residually finite groups are residually finite.
2. $BS(2,1)$ is residually finite (as every $B(m,n)$ with $m=1$ or $n=1$ or $m=n$).
3. Thompson's group $F$ [isn't residually finite](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13597/is-thompsons-group-f-residually-finite).